# Load a GeoJSON layer with QGIS's Python module

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis

I have been able to load a GeoJSON file into QGIS by simply clicking "Add Vector Layer", and selecting my file to load.

Now I'm using the `qgis.core` Python package, and I'm trying to load the GeoJSON file as a layer. I'm following instructions from the [QGIS Python Cookbook - Loading Layers](http://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/loadlayer.html) section; but I can't find how to specify that I'm loading a GeoJSON file.

I've tried:

```
QgsVectorLayer("my_geo.json","mygeojson","geojson")
```

and

```
QgsVectorLayer("my_geo.json","mygeojson","json")
```

to no avail. Any advice on what I could do?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the OGR library, there is a [complete list of supported filetypes](http://www.gdal.org/ogr_formats.html).

From the [QGIS Python Cookbook - Loading Layers](http://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/loadlayer.html):

> OGR library (shapefiles and many other file formats) — data source is the path to the file

```
vlayer = QgsVectorLayer("my_geo.json","mygeojson","ogr")
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(vlayer)
```